# Visual Studio 2013 css outline

Tags: css, visual-studio-2013

Until Visual Studio 2010, when opening a CSS file a window with all the classes and IDs opened automatically to help CSS file navigation.

In Visual Studio 2013, I cannot find this option; am I missing something, or has Microsoft decided that the feature is not useful anymore?

[image]

Comment: In VS 2012, I can open a CSS file and then View -> Other Windows -> Document Outline. Then the next time I open a CSS file, it also automatically shows the Document Outline. Are you saying that no longer happens in VS 2013?

Comment: I am afraid is not visible in VS 2013; see image above. Thanks for your help though!

Comment: In your screenshot it is in the View menu itself, 9th item in the list.

Comment: but it does not work for CSS; With a CSS file opened I get an empty list

Comment: infact.. with a CSS file opened that option (9th in the list) does not even show up; just tried now

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Starting from the same point, we leverage [Dependency Graphs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee842619.aspx).
Thanks to MEF, VS Solution Explorer is listening to imported graph providers. So we jumped on it in order to    bring back a document outline "like" experience for css files. The result is a VS extension available here: http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/b6dd8050-77fa-4dba-998f-dabdd255d96d

Comment: Your extension is great. Can you please make an update for visual studio 2015, which at least includes the CSS Tree View functionality of the extension (for v1.0)? I think this is so important and desperately missing from VS 2015 and your extension is the only one offering this solution, and it looks to do it perfectly. Thanks man.

Comment: We could use one for VS 2017 as well.